# Find related rows from a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe type (name, id, Dept, DeptId):

```
john doe  | J30 | NSL | 01
max payne | M23 | ATL | 22
doe john  | D02 | NSL | 01
joyee     | J04 | NSL | 01
payne max | P04 | ATL | 22
```

Some data was wrongly entered and new ID's where created. I'm trying to get a list

```
J30 -> [ J30,D02 ]
M23 -> [ M23,P04 ]
D02 -> [ J30,D02 ]
J04 -> [ J04 ]
P04 -> [ M23,P04 ]
```

Ultimately remove duplicates

```
U1 -> [ J30,D02 ]  
U2 -> [ M23,P04 ]
U3 -> [ J04 ]
```

Dataset I have is huge, I'm unable to find anyways through spark to get the job done. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is called df, and the order of the first name and second name is the mistake happened in the data set, then it can be grouped up using the reduceByKey method.

```
df.map(row => (row(0).toString.split(" ").toSet, row(1))).
   reduceByKey(Set(_, _)).collect

res41: Array[(scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], Any)] = 
       Array((Set(joyee),J04), (Set(john, doe),Set(J30, D02)), (Set(max, payne),Set(M23, P04)))
```